# Excel formula to identify same book title but different edition in a list of repeating values

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel 2010 list with three columns:book title, edition and barcode of the copy. I want to identify from the book title and edition columns those that are of the same title but have different editions. Titles may be repeated with the same edition if there is more than one copy of the book:

[sample Excel list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFZ3C.jpg)

Ideally, in a fourth column, if the title is repeated but the edition is not, a value is returned such as TRUE, otherwise FALSE if it isn't:

[sample Excel list with 4th column value indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPrVJ.jpg)

I have tried some IF functions i.e. =IF(AND(A3=A2, B3=B2), "TRUE", "FALSE") but it's not really working. I don't know if this is the right approach but I'm really stuck on it - any advice on the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

@Giovanni: I tried the updated IF formula and the result is as follows:

[sample Excel with IF formula applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIU6Q.jpg)

It still doesn't capture only those cells with same titles but different editions. Any ideas?

Comment: if I understand correctly, assuming the data is sorted by title and edition, you want to check if either the row before or the row after contain the same title but with a different edition... in case of no duplicates you have just to complete your formula: =IF(OR(AND((A2=A1),(B2<>B1)), AND(A2=A3),(B2<>B3)), "TRUE", "FALSE")

Comment: @Giovanni...I tried the formula but all the values returned as TRUE. The list is sorted by Title ascending. The requirement would be:if values in rows A1(Title) & B1(Edition) are the same as rows A2&B2 then formula in C1 and C2=FALSE (same titles same editions). If A1 matches A2 but B1 doesn't match B2 then C1 and C2=TRUE (so same titles with different editions). Then if A2 didn't match A3 (so different title in A3) then the formula would check if A3&B3 matched A4&B4 and if so, then C3&C4=FALSE and so on. The list will have duplicate and unique A&B values.

Comment: sorry, reasoning right, formula messed up. Sort the data by title AND edition. The formula =IF( OR ( AND( (A2=A1), (B2=B1) ) , AND( (A2=A3), (B2=B3) ) ), "false", "true") says: if the row is equal to the one before (title and edition) or is equal to the one after, then "false" (else "true"). Remember to copy the formula while editing the cell, not as a "paste" to the cell otherwise the formula doesn't get updated for the current row

Comment: @Giovanni. thanks again! The formula almost works ; I've added a screenshot to the original question if you are still interested.

Comment: Check again because there must be some other problems: I checked the formula on the data you post and it works as desired